# Bottom navigation using android support library and fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview

I have downloaded **https://www.androidhive.info/2017/12/android-working-with-bottom-navigation/** this code.After running the bottom tab is working fine,but when i am clicking on android back button that time the fragment is coming one step back,**but the bottom navigation item is not coming as per fragment.**
[image]
Suppose i have clicked "cart" and the fragment shows "My Cart" ,After this when i am clicking android back button ,the fragment is showing "My Gifts" but bottom navigation is still on "Cart".I want bottom tab should also come one step back.But I am not getting what is the problem here.Can anyone please help me out with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do one change. remove "transaction.addToBackStack(null);"

Why

**FragmentTransaction addToBackStack (String name)**

Add this transaction to the back stack. This means that the transaction will be remembered after it is committed, and will reverse its operation when later popped off the stack.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#addToBackStack(java.lang.String)

```
 private void loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        // load fragment
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment);

      /* Comment this line and it should work!*/
        //transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }
```

Comment: If I remove  "transaction.addToBackStack(null);" ,then on Android Back button click App is closing. I want like on Android back button click it should go to previous fragment.
Suppose i am in fragment 2 now, i moved to fragment 3 by clicking bottom item "Tab3". At this point when i click Android back button ,it should go to Fragment 2.@Pankaj

Comment: You can do one thing keep addToBackState() method. and to update tab label and selection create callback interface and implement with Activity class and when Fragment is visible update Tab selection as well